# presentViewController crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

While in iOS 7 everything works as a charm, *presentViewController:* function crashes when used more than one time in iOS 8.

```
var navigationController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! UINavigationController
presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The above code is executed once, without any problem, the *navigationController* shows perfectly. Closing this *navigationController* and executing the above code again makes the application to crash with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

The code used to dismiss the *navigationController* is the following one:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Note 1: *storyboard* and *navigationController* properties always have the correct instances. I've made sure myself through the virtual console.

Note 2: It's not always on the second time, but on the third or fourth iteration.

Can someone give me a clue on why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time and testing in different devices, I've realized that this is a bug of iOS 8.0.0. Bug that was solved between iOS8.0.1-8.0.3.

We have different devices with different iOS versions in my office and the problem only arises in a 8.0.0 device.

Answer (score 0):

Enable zombies, and enable exception breakpoints to see the exact line for the crash.

Comment: the exact line for the crash is : presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)